# How to create method with parameter in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I am learning Mockito, So I am new to Mockito.
Can make mockito method parameterised? eg. I have one class (**ABC.java**) where I have few methods with @Test annotations like

```
@Test
public void addition() {
}
```

And I am invoking them through another Test class (**testClass.java**).

```
  Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(ABC.class);
  for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
     System.out.println(failure.toString());
  }

  System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
```

So I want to invoke an addition method with a parameter from the test class(**testClass.java**).

Comment: Can you put the parameters directly into the class `ABC`? Because then you can use [JUnit's Parameterized runner](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html).

Comment: Are you mixing your "main" code and test code within `ABC` class? That sounds bizarre to me, but trying to keep my mind open :-)

Comment: Joel,
No. ABC.java is class where I have Tests with @Test annotations.
Where "main" is another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito allows to mock class. Here you don't need to mock anything.

> So I want to invoke an addition method with a parameter from the test
>   class(testClass.java).

`JUnitCore.runClasses()` run test classes passed as parameter. That doesn't provide a way to pass parameters to the test class methods.
So you should parameterize the `addition()` test method from the test class itself by using `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`.
More information [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests).